# Disable hardware acceleration Cordova Visual Studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I´m having perfomance problems on an Android application built in Cordova with Visual Studio 2013.

I read this questions:

[Phonegap - cordova is laggy and slow on android and iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825350/phonegap-cordova-is-laggy-and-slow-on-android-and-ios-devices)

[How do I set a background image on the WebView on Cordova/PhoneGap for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068541/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-on-the-webview-on-cordova-phonegap-for-android)

[Slow page transitions on Android with hardware acceleration on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546521/slow-page-transitions-on-android-with-hardware-acceleration-)

and they talk about a file "src/com/.../MyApp.java" for disable hardware acceleration with this line:

super.appView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

My question is: Where is this file? I´m using Visual Studio 2013, and I can't find it.

Thanks!! Sorry for my english.